# addEventListener redirects to the same page with a '?' at the end of the url

Tags: javascript

After I click the button or click the send button here's what happens:

**HTML super simplified code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <!-- Page Preloder -->

    <!-- Header section -->
    <header class="header-section">

                        <form class="header-search-form">
                            <input id= "searchBarP" type="text" placeholder="Search on divisima ....">
                            <button id= "searchIconP"><i class="flaticon-search"></i></button>
                            <script>

                            var searchBarP = document.getElementById("searchBarP");

                            searchBarP.addEventListener("searchP",function(){
                                alert("Trial");
                         });
                         </script>
                        </form>


    </header>
    <!-- Header section end -->


    </body>
</html>
```

**Here what happens before clicking the button:**

[image: before]

**After:**

[image: after]

Comment: The before and after URLs are the same.

Comment: You can you form action and method
<form action="/index.html" method="get">

Comment: I have no idea what's going on, but if you want to prevent your form from changing page location you can use preventDefault for a from submit `document.querySelector('.header-search-form').addEventListener('submit', e => { e.preventDefault(); });`

Answer (score 0):

Your button doesn't have a [type](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp) and the default type, in this case, is "submit". Since you also didn't specify the [form's method](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp), it defaults to GET. This method appends all parameters to the URL after a question mark, that's why you see it after clicking the button.

**Solution 1:**

If you want both the button and the searchbar to perform the same action, listen for the submit event:

```
<form class="header-search-form" id="form">
    <input id="searchBarP" type="text" placeholder="Search on divisima ....">
    <button type="submit" id="searchIconP"><i class="flaticon-search"></i></button>
    <script>
        const form = document.getElementById("form");
        form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("Trial");
        });
    </script>
</form>
```

**Solution 2:**

Set the button's type to "button" in order to prevent it from submitting the form.

```
<form class="header-search-form">
    <input id="searchBarP" type="text" placeholder="Search on divisima ....">
    <button type="button" id="searchIconP"><i class="flaticon-search"></i></button>
    <script>
        const searchBarP = document.getElementById("searchBarP");
        searchBarP.addEventListener("searchP", function() {
            alert("Trial");
        });
    </script>
</form>
```

Keep in mind, though, that your `searchP` listener won't work because there's no event called "searchP". If you want to separate the behaviour of clicking the button and hitting "enter" while typing in the search bar, you can do something like this:

```
<form class="header-search-form">
    <input id="searchBarP" type="text" placeholder="Search on divisima ....">
    <button type="submit" id="searchIconP"><i class="flaticon-search"></i></button>
    <script>
        const searchIconP = document.getElementById("searchIconP");
        const searchBarP = document.getElementById("searchBarP");
        searchIconP.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); //Remove this if you want to submit the form when you click the button
            alert("Button click");
        });
        searchBarP.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13){
                alert("Search bar enter hit");
                e.preventDefault(); //Remove this if you want to submit the form when you hit enter while typing in the search bar
            }
        });
    </script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
searchBarP.addEventListener("searchP",function(){
alert("Trial");
});
```

The first parameter of `addEventListener` should be an `event`. You have `searchP` which is the element. Try putting `click` instead.